# How to I auto-update a clock in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a simple web based clock app using pure java-script. I think the general code is right, but I'm not sure how to automatically call the function at a set interval of time. I thought the window.onload, followed by the setInterval method would do this. But it's not automatically updating every half second as I expected. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!doctype html>

<html>

    <head>
        <title>Real Time Clock</title>
        <script>

            var time, h, m, s, track;
            track = 0;
            window.onload = function() { setInterval( timeNow(), 100); }

            function timeNow() {

              time = new Date();
              track += 1;
              h = time.getHours();
              m = time.getMinutes();
              s = time.getSeconds();
              if ( s < 10 ) { s = "0" + s; } /* we add a 0 in front of s, when it is lower than 10, because that's what most clocks display, this is for the human user rather than for any need by the computer */
              document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = h + ':' + m + ':' + s;
              document.getElementById("track").innerHTML = track;

            }

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <span id="time">~Waiting for time update.</span><br>
        <span id="track"></span>


    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work fine. Just needed to change

```
window.onload = function() { setInterval( timeNow(), 100); }
```

to

```
 window.onload = function() { setInterval( timeNow, 100); }
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>

    <head>
        <title>Real Time Clock</title>
        <script>

            var time, h, m, s, track;
            track = 0;
            window.onload = function() { setInterval( timeNow, 100); }

            function timeNow() {

              time = new Date();
              track += 1;
              h = time.getHours();
              m = time.getMinutes();
              s = time.getSeconds();
              if ( s < 10 ) { s = "0" + s; } /* we add a 0 in front of s, when it is lower than 10, because that's what most clocks display, this is for the human user rather than for any need by the computer */
              document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = h + ':' + m + ':' + s;
              document.getElementById("track").innerHTML = track;

            }

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <span id="time">~Waiting for time update.</span><br>
        <span id="track"></span>


    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `setInterval(timeNow,100);` instead of `setInterval(timeNow(),100);`

```js
            var time, h, m, s, track;
            track = 0;
            window.onload = function() { 
              var start = setInterval(timeNow,100);
            }

            function timeNow() {

              var time = new Date();
              track += 1;
              h = time.getHours();
              m = time.getMinutes();
              s = time.getSeconds();
      
              if ( s < 10 ) { s = "0" + s; } 
              document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = h + ':' + m + ':' + s;
              document.getElementById("track").innerHTML = track;

            }
```

```html
     

        <span id="time">~Waiting for time update.</span><br>
        <span id="track"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an `undefined` (as the result of calling `timeNow`) to `setInterval`. You need to pass the function, so the code will be:

```js
window.onload = function() { setInterval(timeNow, 100); }
```